# Moduli of Continuity of finite family of maps

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Could anyone tell me how to define moduli of continuity for a finite family of Lipschitz self-maps on some complete, separable metric space?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition I'm familiar with.

Given a family $\mathcal F$ of functions between two fixed metric spaces $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$, we say that a function $\rho\colon \mathbf R_+\to \mathbf R_+$ is its modulus of continuity if it has the property that for every $f\in \mathcal F$, every pair $x_1,x_2$ of points in $X$ and every real $\varepsilon\in\mathbf R_+$, we have that if $d_X(x_1,x_2)<\rho(\varepsilon)$, then $d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2))<\varepsilon$.

This is the only sensible definition that I can think of (well, except for trivial variations, like additional constraints about $\rho$ like monotonicity, or changing the inequality into a non-strict one). Whether $\mathcal F$ is finite or not, and whether $X,Y$ are separable or complete does not matter.

Comment: Thanks for your help, could you be more informal and say few words for (1) why do we need it, why it is helpful to define such notions (Motivation, a big picture may be)? (2) What does geometrically it says? and (3) Since I have some say 9 different Lipschitz maps with 9-different Lipschitz constants, how the situation in my case?

Comment: About (3), in this case, the simplest modulus would be a linear function, with the slope being the minimum of the Lipschitz constants. I can't tell you how it helps in your scenario (I don't know it). The applications I'm aware of are in finding convergent sequences of continuous functions, see e.g. Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

Comment: Oh, and geometrically it means that if you move no further than $\rho(\varepsilon) $, the value of any function won't move further than $\varepsilon$.